# Regarding doubt in proof that every modular function can be represented as rational function of J.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, modular-function

I am self studying analytic number theory from Tom M. Apostol *Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory* and I am stuck on this theorem on page 40.

> Theorem 2.8. *Every rational function of $J$ is a
>   modular function. Conversely, every modular function
>   can be expressed as a rational function of $J$.*
>
> PROOF. The first part is clear. To prove the second,
>   suppose $f$ has zeros at $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n$ and poles
>   at $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$ with the usual conventions about
>   multiplicities. Let $$g(\tau) = \prod_{k=1}^n  \frac{ J(\tau) - J( z_k) } { J(\tau) - J( p_k) }   $$ 
>   where a factor $1$ is inserted whenever $ z_k $ or $ p_k $  is $ \infty $ . Then $g$ has the same zeros 
>   and poles as $f$ in the closure of $R_\Gamma$, each
>   with proper multiplicity. Therefore, $\,f/g\,$ has no
>   zeros or poles and must be constant, so $\,f\,$ is a
>   rational function.

I am not able to understand "where a factor $1$ is inserted whenever $ z_k $ or $ p_k $  is $ \infty $".

I am not able to understand what purpose introducing this factor solves.

The proof continues but except the above line. I have no doubts in proof.

Can someone please explain. I have thought a lot about it but I can't get it.

Also, I have no help as I am self studying and the university in which I am studying doesn't have a number theorist.

Comment: You may find my answer is more informative than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific question was

> I am not able to understand what purpose introducing this factor solves.

The explanation goes back to the beginning of of Section $2.4$
on Modular Functions on page $34$ where he **defines** what it
means for a modular function to have a pole of order $\,m\,$ at $\,i\infty\,$ using the leading term in its Fourier expansion. 
By the way, the statement of Theorem $2.8$ should have $\,\infty\,$ replaced with $\,i\infty\,$ instead.

The key observation is that you have to distinguish between
an ordinary pole or zero and a pole or zero at $\,i\infty.\,$
A similar situation holds for rational functions defined on
the [extended complex plane Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere).
Each ordinary zero or pole at $\,w\,$ is associated with factors of $\,F_w(z):=(z-w)\,$ raised to an integer power whose absolute value is the multiplicity of the zero or pole. But $\,F_\infty(z) = (z-\infty)\,$ is not a valid function.

However, all of these $\,F_w(z)\,$ factors have a
similar behavior as $\,z\to\infty,\,$ in that they are 
[asymptotically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) equivalent.
Because of this behavior at $\,\infty,\,$ we can **define** the order of a zero or pole at $\,\infty\,$ so that each factor of
$\,(z-w)\,$ is regarded as a pole at $\,\infty\,$
and further **define** $\,F_\infty(z):=1.\,$ This is essentially the
projective viewpont. Using this convention, we can now state
that any non-constant rational function has a equal number of zeros and poles (up to multiplicity), but some of the zeros and poles may be at $\,\infty.\,$

For example, the rational function $\,F_w(z)\,$
is said to have a simple zero at $\,w\,$ and a simple pole
at $\,\infty.\,$ Thus, we can now write
 $\,z-w = F_w(z)/F_\infty(z).\,$ Any products and quotients
of such factors would have an equal number of $\,F\,$ factors
in the numerator and denominator. A similar situation arises
in the case of modular functions with the point $\,\infty\,$
replaced by $\,i\infty\,$ and $\,F_w(z)\,$ replaced with
$\,J(z)-J(w).\,$

Comment: @ Somos Thanks a lot for such a clear and intuitive explanation!!

Comment: I have earlier self studied Tom M Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory after doing a course in complex analysis, but my instructor at university didn't even mentioned analytic continuation, although then I self studied it from Complex Variables with Applications from Ponnusamy and Silvermann and then studied Chapter 12 and 13 of Apostol introduction to analytic number theory but I don't feel sometimes comfortable in analytic continuation. Can you please suggest some good reference book for Analytic Continuation which has explained analytic continuation in detail and also contains..

Comment: exercises based on analytic continuation which I will try

Comment: @user686624 You have a good question about learning Analytic Continuation. I suggest you ask this as a new question jere on MSE and will probably get good answers. Please include some of your requirements and history as you stated above in your comment.

Comment: Ok  I will ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

Let $q_k$ be the poles of $f$ on the upper half-plane. Then $$g(t)=f(t) \prod_k (J(t)-J(q_k))$$ has no poles on the upper half-plane, it has a pole of order $n$ at $i\infty$ thus $g(t)-C_n J(t)^n$ has a pole of order $\le n-1$ at $i\infty$, repeat until $$h(t)=g(t)-\sum_{m=1}^n C_m J(t)^m$$ has no pole, since the modular curve is a compact Riemann surface, $|h(t)|$ attains its maximum at $a$, taking a chart $\phi(0)=a$ then $h \circ \phi$ is an analytic function attaining its maximum modulus which implies it is constant, by analytic continuation $h$ is constant and $$f(t) = \frac{h(a)+\sum_{m=1}^n C_mJ(t)^m}{\prod_k (J(t)-J(q_k))}$$

Comment: How does this answer the question about factors of $1$?

Comment: No idea of what you mean. The OP is asking about the proof that the field is $\Bbb{C}(j)$, there are two ways: moving all the poles at $i\infty$ as I did, or constructing a rational function in $j$ with the same zeros/poles, obtaining a function $k$ with no pole nor zero so that $k,1/k$ are analytic thus are bounded thus constant. You didn't expose any of those (whereas they do take a few lines). Before that we need to show that $X_0(1)$ is a compact Riemann surface and that $j$ has no zeros on $\Bbb{H}$, which depends on our definition of $\Delta$ as a product of as $E_4^3-E_6^2$

Comment: The OP states: 'I am not able to understand "where a factor $1$ is inserted whenever $z_k$ or $p_k$ is $\infty$" The proof continues but except the above line. I have no doubts in proof.' The OP already has the proof in Apostol, but does not understand one little detail. Your answer is not explaining that detail. Also I doubt the OP knows what a compact Riemann surface is.

Comment: Sure but there is no alternative. This is what your answer is about : an informal discussion that there is a concept of divisor of zeros/poles on $X_0(1)$ similar to $\Bbb{C}\cup \infty$. I didn't look at Apostol, I don't like his books, I prefer MSE.