# Applications of two representation theorems of elliptic functions and modular forms

Tags: modular-forms, elliptic-functions

I'd like to know some elementary applications of these theorems, and also some examples of how one could work out the representations in question given a particular $f$.

> If $f$ is an elliptic function it can always be written as $$f(z) =
>  R_1 [\mathcal{P(z)}] + \mathcal{P}'(z) R_2[\mathcal{P}(z)]$$ for some
>   rational function $R_1, \, R_2$ where $\mathcal{P}$ is the Weierstrass
>   function.

As well as

> If $f$ is a modular function it can always be written as a rational
>   function of Klein's $j$-invariant.

References are also greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorems are a relatively advanced part of "The Elliptic Realm". They are of use if you already have
 an elliptic function or a modular function and you
want to express it in a simple form relative to $\,\wp(z)\,$ or $\,j(\tau).\,$

To actually use the result is not hard. For example, the
$\,j\,$-function has an inverse $\,g(z)\,$ which satisfies
$\,z = j(g(z))\,$ and $\,\tau = g(j(\tau)).\,$ Thus, if you
have another modular function $\,f(\tau),\,$ then find the
power series expansion of $\,R(z) := f(g(z))\,$ where the
function $\,R(z)\,$ is rational according to the theorem.
Of course, there are other ways to find the rational function $\,R(z)\,$ using undetermined coefficients
for instance. There is a recent [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3462751/) "Regarding doubt in proof that every modular function can be represented as rational function in J" which refers
to a book by Apostol. There is a [pdf Lecture Notes](https://Fmath.mit.edu/classes/18.783%2F2017/LectureNotes20.pdf) which states

> Theorem $20.8.$ Every modular function for $\Gamma(1)$ is a rational function of $\,j(\tau).\,$

For elliptic functions, the function $\,\wp(z)\,$ is even
and $\,\wp'(z)\,$ is odd. Thus, given an elliptic function
$\,f(z)\,$ we can split it into its even and odd part. For example, $\,f(z) = f_1(z) + \wp'(z) f_2(z)\,$
where both $\,f_1(z)\,$ and $\,f_2(z)\,$ are even
functions of $\,z.\,$ The $\,\wp\,$ function
(or rather $\,1/\sqrt{\wp(z)}\,$) has an inverse $\,g(z) = z + \frac{c_2}2 z^5 + \frac{c_3}2 z^7 + O(z^9)\,$ which satisfies
$\,z = 1/\sqrt{\wp(g(z))} = g(1/\sqrt{\wp(z)}).\,$ Thus,
$\,R_1(z) = f_1(g(1/\sqrt{z}))\,$ and
$\,R_2(z) = f_2(g(1/\sqrt{z}))\,$ where the functions
$\,R_1\,$ and $\,R_2\,$ are rational according to the
theorem. This is referenced in the Wikipedia article
[Weierstrass's elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) which states

> The totality of meromorphic double periodic functions with given period defines an algebraic
>   function field associated to that curve. It can be
>   shown that this field is $$\mathbb{C}(\wp,\wp'),$$
>   so that all such functions are rational functions
>   in the Weierstrass function and its derivative.

This theorem is also mentioned in Abramowitz and
Stegun's *Handbook of Mathematical Functions*, section
18.11 page 651:

> If $f(z)$ is any elliptic function and $\cal{P}(z)$
>   has the same periods, write
>   $$ {\bf 18.11.1} \quad f(z) =
> \frac12 [f(z)+f(-z)] + \frac12[\{f(z)-f(-z)\}
> \{\cal{P}'(z)\}^{-1}]\cal{P}'(z). $$
>
> Since both brackets represent even elliptic functions, we ask how to express an even elliptic
>   function $\,g(z)\,$ (of order $2k$) in terms of
>   $\cal{P}(z).\,$

There follows equation $18.11.2$ which expresses
$\,g(z)\,$ as an explicitly factorized rational
function in $\cal{P}(z)\,$ with linear factors.